# Horizontal stacked unique 100% bar chart plotly python

Tags: python, pandas, plotly, bar-chart

I want to plot a 100% horizontal bar with plotly.

The imports and data are the following.

```
import pandas as pd
from plotly.offline import plot
import plotly.graph_objects as go

df = pd.DataFrame([["Blue", 100 , 10.0],
                   ["Green", 30 , 3.0],
                   ["Red", 650, 65.0],
                   ["White", 65, 6.5],
                   ["Gray", 70, 7.0],
                   ["green", 50, 5.0],
                   ["white", 35 , 3.5]],
                  columns=["color", "total", "percentage"])
```

I'd like to have all colors in a single bar (adding to 100%), different colors for each one and ignore cases, having "Green" and "green" counting as one "Green" (5.0+3.0=8.0), as in the image below:

[image: stackedhorizontalbar]

But when I try the following (https://plotly.com/python/horizontal-bar-charts/ <>), I'm getting a error:

```
import plotly
colors = plotly.colors.qualitative.D3

fig = go.Figure()
for i in range(0, len(df['total'][0])):
    for xd, yd in zip(df['total'], df['color']):
        fig.add_trace(go.Bar(
            x=[xd[i]], y=[yd],
            orientation='h',
            marker=dict(
                color=colors[i],
                line=dict(color='rgb(248, 248, 249)', width=1)
            )
        ))
```

Also tried this approach, that gives me one bar per color:

```
fig = go.Figure()
fig.add_trace(go.Bar(
    y=df['color'],
    x=df['percentage'],
    name='Colors',
    orientation='h'
    )
)

fig.update_layout(barmode='stack')
fig.show()
```

How do I get it?

Answer (score 1):

It's not a normal bar chart. You need to manually calculate the bar positions and width based on percentage.

```
# aggregate percentage by color, ignore case
colors = df.groupby(df.color.str.lower()).percentage.sum()

# reorder color index
colors = colors.reindex(['blue', 'green', 'red', 'white', 'gray'])

# calculate x bar positions
x_barpos = colors.cumsum() - colors / 2

# create figure
fig = go.Figure(go.Bar(
    x=x_barpos, 
    y=[1] * len(colors), 
    width=colors, 
    marker_color=colors.index
))

# set x axes labels
fig = fig.update_xaxes(
    tickvals=list(range(0, 101, 25)), 
    ticktext=[str(x)+'%' for x in range(0, 101, 25)], 
    range=[0, 100])

# remove y axes labels
fig = fig.update_yaxes(showticklabels=False, range=[0, 1])

fig.show()
```

[image]